# Cannot assign to variables in other namespaces

Tags: puppet

i've got main puppet class which is added to all servers in my network, let's call it: profile::base.pp:

```
class profile::base {
...
  $agent_zbx_templates = ['OS Linux']
...
  include profile::zabbix::agent
}
```

I hiera file for specific node I've got:

```
classes:
  - profile::haproxy
```

And class `profile::haproxy.pp` I would like to add something to `$agent_zbx_templates` defined in `profile::base.pp`, for example:

```
class profile::haproxy {
    $local_agent_zbx_templates = $profile::base::agent_zbx_templates + ['APP HAProxy']
   class {'profile::base':
    agent_zbx_templates => $local_agent_zbx_templates
   }
}
```

And of course when I try to do puppet agent -t on node I've receive:

```
[root@stress1 ~]# puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: Class[Profile::Base] is already declared; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/profile/manifests/haproxy.pp:48 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/profile/manifests/haproxy.pp:48:3 on node stress1.lb.dc2
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

How can I change agent_zbx_templates (from profile::base) from another class?

Regards,
p.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a class twice on the same node.

However, what you can do is to add a node or environment-specific hiera file. Hiera goes through the hierarchy and uses the first declaration it finds, ignoring later duplicate ones.

hiera.yaml:

```
:hierarchy:
  - "node/%{::fqdn}"
  - "environment/%{::environment}"
  - ...
```

Then, create the folder `node` in your hiera datadir, for example: `/etc/puppetlabs/hieradata/node`. Whenever you put a yaml file with the fqdn as name in there, the class declarations in there will be used and declarations of the same class later are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

What does the title of this question have to do with the content?

This is the only stack exchange question that seems to be related, so I"ll just answer the title here.

So I was doing a thing like:

**modules/xyz/manifests/init.pp**

```
class xyz {
    $xyz::x = 1
    import xyzother
}
```

**modules/xyzother/manifests/init.pp**

```
class xyzother {
    notify{ "x = $xyz::x": }
}
```

and it failed saying the exact quote `Cannot assign to variables in other namespaces` as in your title, but where is anything like this in your question?

So for my problem, it wasn't obvious since this is the same namespace, not another. But the solution was simple... what I did wrong was just that you can't use the namespace name there... only specify it when you are reading the value from another namespace (such as othermodule).

So simply remove the `xyz::` from where it's the local namespace already. Only use that for reading, not variable assignment.